# How can I use Sharepoint Groups to limit viewing and updating of items in a single list?

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, groups

I have a single list with a number of columns.

I want to enable users assigned to specific contribute level groups to be able to contribute to the list and only see the items that they or the people in that group have added to the list.

At the moment I have created my list, broken inheritance, created item level permissions of "added by the user" in both instances.

Or am I confusing the User Groups with the ability of the list to display items created by those user groups?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, SharePoint does not have item-level permission levels.

This situation often we think of creating different views for different groups, but unfortunately, so far there doesn't seem to be such a feature.

In addition, out of the box, we can only add a filter on "[me]", we can't filter on “group”.

As a workaround, I suggest you create a new list and break permission inheritance, only this group has permission to access this list.

Answer (score 0):

you can break role inheritance by item on SP on premise and SP online
[image: onprem]

[image]